# Persistent device naming for Windows 7-partition in Ubuntu

Tags: udev, persistence, partitioning, device-name

I'd like to give the Windows partition of my Ubuntu installation a persistent device name, so different applications (like the local folder-account of my email software, or my local dropbox client) have access to folders and files on this partition via a fixed file path.

As far as I understand (I am a Linux newbie), the easiest way to do this will be to create personal *udev-rules*. I tried to follow several guides like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168221), but these seem specifically written for USB devices. If I follow their steps and type `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sd2)` (`sd2` is my Windows partition), I get, for instance, no `BUS`-value and no `SYSFS{product}`-value either, although both seem to be necessary for writing rules.

Maybe newer Ubuntu versions even have a far more easier way to accomplish this task? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is modify your /etc/fstab file giving the windows partition a fixed mount point.

This is an example: `/dev/sda2  /media/Windows  ntfs    uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137   0   0`

Practically, this line says mount the /dev/sda2 partition to /media/Windows and sets partition permissions.

Every time you turn your computer on the Windows partition will automount on /media/Windows.

Comment: I just modified the fstab-file. It seems to work. Many thanks!!!

Comment: Just for further clarification, can you maybe explain what exactly the expressions `uid=1000`, `gid=1000`, `dmask=027`, `fmask=137`, and the two `0` at the end of the line mean or point to? So I can understand not only _that_ this is the correct solution, but also _why_.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System --> Administration --> Disk Utility and change the file name.

Or use gparted from the ubuntu software centre and right click on the partition drive you want to rename and click label.Now,enter your desirable name.